# Why won't my ScrollViewer Scrollbars appear on the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue with a WPF C# project, where I have a StackPanel on my Form, within that I have a DockPanel which has items added to it programmatically, the problem is that the items are going out of the form's bounds and I would like to scroll through these, I already have a method for "Scrollifying" the items, but for the life of me I can't see why the scrollbars aren't appearing on the screen, am I missing something?

Code is below, any suggestions are more than welcome.

```
 private void ScrollifyStackpanel(StackPanel Panel)
        {
            ScrollViewer SV = new ScrollViewer();
            SV.Height = Panel.ActualHeight;
            SV.Width = Panel.ActualWidth;


            SV.CanContentScroll = true;
            SV.Content = Panel;

        }
```

Xaml

this is the stackpanel containing the (should be) scrollable content

```
<StackPanel Name="divParentPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top"  DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanVerticallyScroll="True">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `ScrollBar` `Visibility`:

```
        ScrollViewer SV = new ScrollViewer();
        SV.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        SV.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
```

> ***Sometimes it can happen that `ScrollViewer` can't detect the necessity of `ScrollBars` at exact moment of size change. It's totally
>   `context` specific but set the `visibility` to `Visible` to be safe always.***

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't doing anything

Comment: @ReeceCottam try it with fix height and width of ScrollViewer. just set it to any size less than the size of panel

Comment: No, still nothing I'm afraid =/

Comment: @ReeceCottam can you provide your other code as well, xaml file code

Comment: @ReeceCottam you have not defined the dockpanel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111747/discussion-between-kylo-ren-and-reece-cottam).

Comment: Oh nevermind, I managed to achieve this by adding a ScrollViewer in XAML =]

Answer (score 0):

@Reece Try by setting the height for stack panel. since StackPanel cannot have dynamic height. Or else you can use Grid instead of StackPanel

Comment: only grid may be able to help not stackpanle

Comment: Yes.Since stackpanel cannot have dynamic height. if you are setting the height for stackpanel based on your content. Then you can able to see the scrollviewer. So its better to use Grid with Row and ColumnDefinitions

Comment: and it doesn't matter what's  the height of stackpanel it can have content of infinnite size, but overflow will not be visible.

Comment: Yes it is a behavior of stack panel. Did you try by setting the height for StackPanel. otherwise you cant.